# Perl PP doesn't include Switch module

Tags: perl, perl-module, par, perl-packager

I created a perl script that includes the `Switch` module.

hello_world.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Switch;
use Data::Dumper;

my $var = "Hello World\n";
print Dumper($var);
```

if I launch `perl hello_world.pl` everything works fine. But if I pack my script with `pp hello_world.pl` and than launch `./a.out` it gives me back this error:

```
Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module) (@INC contains: CODE(0x7fb2631e6a88) /var/folders/rb/2b5sbs355n57svwzjjh7cb9c0000gn/T/par-6967676c6f62616c33/cache-710e967842eb844ab8d6fe5f46968c1b6f49e019/inc/lib /var/folders/rb/2b5sbs355n57svwzjjh7cb9c0000gn/T/par-6967676c6f62616c33/cache-710e967842eb844ab8d6fe5f46968c1b6f49e019/inc CODE(0x7fb262988de0) CODE(0x7fb262989930)) at script/hello_world.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/hello_world.pl line 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ corelist Switch

Data for 2016-05-09
Switch was first released with perl v5.7.3, deprecated (will be CPAN-only) in v5.11.0 and removed from v5.13.1
```

Switch was never a good idea. It's a source filter which means it's a clever party trick but shouldn't be used in production code. For that reason it has removed from Perl several versions ago.

I suspect that you are running your packaged program on a more recent version of Perl than the unpackaged version - one that no longer includes Switch.

You can install Switch on your target system or you can work out how to get `pp` to include the module in the package. But the best solution is to rewrite the code to stop using Switch.

Comment: I get the same problem by using YAML `use YAML`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force the modules to be included, with `-M` option:

```
pp -M Switch -M YAML ...
```